# Pairs of Mathematicians

Tags: mathematicians

In *Hilbert* by Reid, it is noted that Hilbert and Minkowski were great friends and often worked together on problems, seminars, and lectures. This is a similar relationship to the partnership between Hardy and Littlewood. Are there similar examples of strong and lengthy collaborations in mathematics?

Comment: There are way too many examples of long-term collaborators in math. Try to narrow down your request. If you want concrete examples, start here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s_number#Most_frequent_Erd%C5%91s_collaborators

Comment: @MoisheKohan Of course, but the main difference here is that both examples are researchers who have many well known contributions and collaborated for most of their lives together. I suspect there are other well known mathematicians who have a dual colleague.

Comment: Did you look at the table in the link? For instance, 62 joint papers are listed for Erdős and Sárközy. Maybe you mean an exclusive collaboration? (A and B wrote many papers together but hardly any with other mathematicians.) Also, see here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/28892/which-pair-of-mathematicians-has-the-most-joint-papers

Comment: Depends on what you exactly call "strong and lengthy". More than 1/2 of the late 20th century papers on Mathscinet are written in collaboration. Collaborations used to be rare at the time of Hardy and Littlewood, but they are very common nowadays.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko I think the OP is thinking about very high profile, historically well known mathematicians. As far I know, Hilbert was very good in network building, but most practicing mathematicians are lone wolves.

Comment: "most practicing mathematicians are lone wolfs" - This is not true anymore. Choose your favorite great mathematician (after 1980) and look at the publication list. Most papers will be joint.

Answer (score 4):

This is quite common. Some examples of pairs of very strong researchers who published at least $15$ papers together:

- Guillemin and Sternberg.
- Harvey and Lawson.
- Colding and Minicozzi
- Ozsvath and Szabo
- Green and Tao.
- Schoen and Yau.
- Mrowka and Kronheimer
- Atiyah and Bott.
- Atiyah and Singer.

There are of course many more examples, as this list mostly reflects my own interests.